# Green Card - ADIT Styled Photos

Tags: greencard, passport, usa

My wife green card interview is coming shortly, and one of the items they want us to bring is two (2) ADIT Styled photos. From what I've learned is that they are like passport photos, but they take 3/4 of your face which exposes your ear.

We were unable to get information from USCIS live support chat to find ways to getting these photos. One suggested the Post Office and Walgreens, and both either did not know about these photos or can not do them because of the different angle.

Has anyone dealt with getting an ADIT style photo, or knows what is the difference between that and a stamp?

[ADIT Stamp] https://www.simonebertollini.com/2017/10/28/what-is-an-adit-stamp/
[I-551] https://www.uscis.gov/i-9-central/temporary-i-551-stamps-and-mrivs

Comment: I have never heard of this requirement. I also thought that they were not issuing the I-551 stamps anymore. How do you know that you need these ADIT Photos?

Comment: It was listed as documents that we need to bring for my wife's green card interview. They ask for two (2) ADIT-styled photos.

Comment: Was it listed on form 797C?

Comment: @IanDantas I will have to check back when I get home, but this document does not look like the standard document that you normally see from the USCIS. 

It looks ordinary, but this might be because the interview was rescheduled.

Comment: @JeremyTrpka I recently got my green card and they just need passport photos. I got mine from Walgreens. They sent me a "Courtesy Letter to Applicant" on pink paper at some point after initially reviewing my application which said "Two passport-style natural color photos for the applicant".

Answer (score 1):

I was unable to find a place to get ADIT photos, but my wife did submit two passport styled photos, and the interviewer thought it was fine.

And my wife's green card application was approved, and recently got her green card.